# Invalid Syntax with Print Statement

Tags: python-2.7

I have a line of code that is saying that there is invalid syntax in my print statement. Does anyone know about how to fix this? I've tried deleting the parentheses and have tried changing the +'s to ,'s.

```
print(stockName[random] + ' - $' + Names[0, amod] + ' : You have ' + x + ' of this stock')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code given. Is it possible that a previous line has unclosed delimiters of some kind, like parens or brackets?

Comment: I was missing an import

Answer (score 0):

If you use ' x ' with + operator it should be a string else you should use coma.